# Distinct in table join is not working correctly

Tags: sql

Hi i am using distinct in table join but it's not working correctly.only first item working correctly.after that repeating item is getting means in **user.user_id** column  only first user_id get distinct(i am having group identical user_id) .after first ID i am getting repeating id.my query is like below .please help me in this regard.

```
@"distinct timesheet.user_id, timesheet.created_date,"
            + "  [user].first_name,[user].last_name")

            .From(@"timesheet "
                  + "INNER JOIN [user] ON  [user].user_id = timesheet.user_id "
                  + "INNER JOIN timesheet_status ON timesheet.timesheet_status_id = timesheet_status.timesheet_status_id"
```

Comment: The DISTINCT keyword applies to the entire row, so if you have the same user_id with multiple, distinct timesheets you're obviously going to get the user_id displayed multiple times.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist is there is any way to get

Comment: Can you show an example of your data and what you are trying to get as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT     timesheet.user_id
          ,MIN(timesheet.created_date) As first_created_date
          ,MIN([user].first_name) AS first_name
          ,MIN([user].last_name) AS last_name
FROM      timesheet
          INNER JOIN [user] ON  [user].user_id = timesheet.user_id 
          INNER JOIN timesheet_status 
              ON timesheet.timesheet_status_id = timesheet_status.timesheet_status_id
GROUP BY  timesheet.user_id
```

The code above will get the earliest (`MIN`) timesheet for each user_id along with their name. For the latest timesheet you would change the keyword `MIN` to `MAX`.

Comment: afetr executing am getting folowing exception.                        An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'GROUP'.

Comment: @King I have updated my answer as I missed the join condition

Comment: k thanks .Actually i have written the different query and its working.I ll try to replace with the above query